# Identify groups of similar-coloured pixels

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am writing some software that periodically checks a camera image to identify whether an object has been introduced to the viewed scene. I am using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) in my WinForms software to compare two images to create a third. In the third image, a pixel is white if the first two images had a similar-coloured pixel, and black if they were different. So if the user sees a group of black pixels, they will know something has been placed in the scene that wasn't there previously, as seen here:
[image]

The user will not be seeing this image, so I would like my software to identify this for me. I don't need anything too complex from this analysis - just a Boolean for whether something was changed in the scene.

In my mind, there are two approaches to analysing this; counting the number of black pixels in the image, or I could write some algorithm to identify patches of black. My question is about the second approach, since it feels like the more correct approach. The image is a bit too noisy (you can see false positives on straight edges) for me to feel entirely comfortable with counting.

To identify a group, I have considered using some for loops to look at the colours of pixels surrounding every pixel but this seems like it would take forever. My processing time can't take more than a few seconds so I need to be wary of this. Are there cleaner or more-efficient ways to identify groups of similarly-coloured pixels? Or will I need to run loops and be as efficient as possible?

Comment: Maybe you could also ask this question here: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Threshold the image such that black pixels will have value 1 non black will have zero.
2. Use connected component labeling to find all the groups of connected black pixels. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php
3. Filter out the components that are too small or doesn't have the correct shape(for example you can have a long line on the sides so they have a lot of black pixels but you are not expecting to see a long line as a valid group of black pixels)

Answer (score 0):

At this point I assume you have a sense of the scale of the objects that you are interested in capturing.  For example, if you did have an entirely non-black screen (let's ignore noise for the purpose of this discussion), except you have a black pixel object that is only roughly 10 pixels in diameter.  This seems to be frightfully small, and not enough information to be useful.

Once you have determined what is the minimum size of black mass you are willing to accept, I would then go about querying a staggered matrix.

i.e., a pattern like:

[image]

Use a little math to determine what acceptable noise is.

Once you have positive results, (pixels = black), investigate in those sectors.